# Dot behavior in regex patterns

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(".*");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher("true");
System.out.println(m2.matches() + " [" + m2.group() + "]");
```

When I use the code above it is all right. But I don't understand what is going on when I use this regexpr `[.]*`. It prints `false`.

How to make a dot as a specific symbol? Or how to make a class of symbols with any characters without \n and \r?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I don't understand what is going on when I use this regexpr [.]*. It says me false.

Because inside a [character class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), the dot loses its special meaning and will match a plain old dot (the `.` character).

Outside of a character class the dot is a metacharacter that matches any character, excluding newlines (unless you use the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) modifier, of course).

> Or how to make a class of symbols with any characters without \n and \r.

Use a negated character class:

```
 Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[^\\r\n]*");
```

`[^\r\n]` means "match anything that's **not** a `\r` or a `\n`.

Comment: What is the the first backslash right after the caret symbol doing in `[^\\r\n]`?

Answer (score 3):

`.*` means any character 0 or more times
`[.]*` means dot character 0 or more times

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is the character class and most inside it stand for their actual symbol. Dot in this case would just be a dot and not a dot with special meaning in regex.

Comment: How to make it as a specific symbol

Comment: How to make a class with any character?

Answer (score 0):

The dot `.` is a  [predefined character class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html). It matches any character (may or may not match line terminators). If want to define character class that includes a [range](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) of values, you can use `[]`.